# How to add a bottom row that tallies total from a column in PHP MySQL PDO and display it?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my very first question here in stackoverflow, so please bear with me :)

I am a newbie with PDO PHP. I currently am "maintaining" a bespoke CRM for a company I am working for (got accepted recently after graduating). As a fresh grad, I was able to "fix" and implement things, but this one has me stumped.

I would like to tally the "total hours" in the bottom row as shown in the pic down below for each and every service table.

[CRM in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEJMe.png)

The code has been drummed up by my predecessor that has left but is still willing to help. I have been trying to make changes but there is none that sticks nor works. I am out of options. I have added comments to it to help me navigate things.

```
<?php // Start PHP2
// Query SQL Table for the Sum total of hours and display at the bottom of the table for each service
$sqltot = "
SELECT SUM(cn_hours) AS total_hours 
  FROM Casenotes 
 WHERE cn_date_service BETWEEN '" . $agreementstart . "' AND '" . $agreementend . "' 
   AND part_id = :id 
   AND cn_group = :groupid
";

// PDO prepare statement
$st = $pdo->prepare($sqltot);

$st->bindvalue(':id', $partid);
$st->bindvalue(':groupid', $serviceid);

// mysqli_fetch_assoc equivalent for PDO
$st->execute(); 


// this is supposedly what prints our table gathered from SQL Query gathered from above
foreach($st as $rowst) {
    echo $rowst['total_hours'];
}

if($rowservagr['sa_closed'] == 0){
 ?> <!-- End PHP2 -->

    
<form method="post" action="inc/casenote-admin.php" style="float:right;margin-right:20px;">
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="part_id" value="<?php echo $partid; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="cnservice_id" value="<?php echo $serviceid; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="cn_staff_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="newnote" />
                        
                        <button type="submit" name="submitcase" style="border:none;color:#FFFF00;background-color:transparent;font-size:15px;cursor:pointer;">new casenote <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                        <?php
                        } // closes Agreement is not closed
                        ?>
                    
                </div>
                
            <table style="width:100%;font-size:13px;margin-bottom:20px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="cellfirstdocs date-col">service</th>
                        <th class="celldocs date-col">time</th>
                        <th class="celldocs by-col">by</th>
                        <th class="celldocs type-col">type</th>
                        <th class="celldocs">notes</th>
                        <th class="celldocs view-col"></th>
                        <th class="celldocs hours-col">hours</th>
                        <th class="celldocs view-col"></th>
                        <?php if($rowservagr['sa_closed'] == 0){ ?>
                        <th class="celldocs edit-col">edit</th>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
            
                    // select all records from docs table for this participant id
                    // $sqldc = "SELECT * FROM Casenotes WHERE part_id = :id AND cn_group = :groupid AND cn_staff_id = :staffid ORDER BY cn_date_service DESC";
                    $sqldc = "SELECT * FROM Casenotes WHERE part_id = :id AND cn_group = :groupid ORDER BY cn_date_service DESC, cn_from DESC";
            
                    $sd = $pdo->prepare($sqldc);
        
                    $sd->bindvalue(':id', $partid);
                    $sd->bindvalue(':groupid', $serviceid);
                    // $sd->bindvalue(':staffid', $user_id);
    
                    $sd->execute();

                    foreach($sd as $rowd) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="parent" id="<?php echo $rowd['cn_id']; ?>">
                        <td class="cellfirstdocs"><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($rowd['cn_date_service'])); ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"><?php echo date("g:i A", strtotime($rowd['cn_from'])); ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"><?php echo StaffUsernameInitials($rowd['cn_staff_id']); ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"><?php echo CNTypeName($rowd['cn_type']); ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"><?php echo $rowd['cn_summary']; ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs ctr"><span class="btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></span></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"><?php echo $rowd['cn_hours']; ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs ctr"><?php if($rowd['cn_attach'] != ''){ ?>
                                    <a href="/dcs/c_note/<?php echo $rowd['cn_attach']; ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <?php
                                        $name =  $rowd['cn_attach'];
                                        $extension = substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1);
                                        if($extension == 'pdf'){ ?>
                                        <i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>
                                        <?php
                                        } else if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'png'){
                                        ?>
                                        <i class="fas fa-file-image"></i>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php } ?></td>
                        
                        <?php if($rowservagr['sa_closed'] == 0){
                        ?>
                        <td class="celldocs">
                            <form method="post" action="inc/casenote-admin.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cn_id" value="<?php echo $rowd['cn_id']; ?>" />
                                
                                <input type="hidden" name="editnote" />
                                
                                <button type="submit" name="submitcase" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;cursor:pointer;">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <?php
                        } // closes if not admin type
                        ?>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="child-<?php echo $rowd['cn_id']; ?>">
                        <td class="cellfirstdocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"><?php echo nl2br($rowd['cn_note']); ?></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                        <td class="celldocs"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    } // closes for each loop
                    ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: Insert your "totals" row after the loop ends, after `// closes for each loop`. And tally your "totals" data inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am thinking of maybe separating each table for now, so that in the future, I might be able to edit each and every single one separately and easily

Comment: How do you decide which variables get properly prepared and bound, and which don't? :-(

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt because I am a newbie as well, but my take is that anything that requires  to be: posted, requires user input and submitted. Either that belongs in that category should be prepared to avoid sql injection. I most likely missed a few things, but I am sure the more advanced programmers here can provide a more definite answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason why keeping your presentation logic and database logic separate as much as possible is a brilliant idea.

Fetch all your results into an array before displaying any HTML. Do all calculations beforehand and then only display the HTML table.

```
$sqldc = "SELECT * 
    FROM Casenotes 
    WHERE part_id = :id AND cn_group = :groupid 
    ORDER BY cn_date_service DESC, cn_from DESC";
            
$sd = $pdo->prepare($sqldc);

$sd->execute([
    'id' => $partid,
    'groupid' => $serviceid
]);

$results = $sd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_hours = array_sum(array_column($results, 'cn_hours'));
```

Then you can just add one more `<tr>` after your `foreach` loop and print out the total tally.